# ejabberd, how to block/acl the register msg in the server from one specific IP and allow other IP

Tags: filter, ejabberd

ejabberd verion 18.06.

how to block/acl the register msg in the server from one specific IP and allow other IP. ?

I am able to block completely  with both IPs at api_permissions > public_commands.  Multiple who & what commands are not accepted. & logical IP to what commands are not available.

Is there a way to block specific commands say "register" over http from a specific source IP ?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea I saw somewhere else, but I haven't tried it, yu can try to prepend a ! like this:

```
api_permissions:
  "disable some":
    who:
      - ip: "127.66.66.66"
    what:
      - "!register"
      - "*"
  "test commands":
    who:
      - ip: "127.0.0.1/8"
    what:
      - "*"
```